# jQuery Fullcalendar - in week view, mark all days with color, if event allDay is true

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In week agenda view, if any event is `allDay:true`, mark this event days (from start date till end date) with different background (like current day), vertically.

I am thinking to clone elements from `All day` cell, if there are one, and after change height, background color, etc. But I think it is bad idea.

Maybe you can advice something better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) to get the days associated with the event and color the appropriately (fc-col0, fc-col1... is the class to key off)

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    if (view.name == 'agendaWeek' && event.allDay) {
        $('.fc-col' + event.start.getDay()).not('.fc-widget-header').css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
}
```

If your all day events can span multiple days you will need to take that into account also.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mEwsK/)

Comment: I modified a little [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj3Ld/) - it is throwing error in jsFiddle, but working nice on my system. Thanks!